# Wget mirror should treat xml as html

Tags: wget, html, mirroring, xml

I want to make a mirror of a site that has a dynamic sitemap in XML form.

Of course I want that sitemap downloaded and processed as if it were an html file.

I tried the `-F` flag for this file, but it didn't work, saying that it didn't find any URLs inside the file.

Currently I assume that this won't work this way (because wget is not for xml), but wanted to ask to make sure I'm not overlooking something.

The content of the xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://MY_SITE/wp-content/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/sitemap.xsl"?><!-- sitemap-generator-url="http://www.arnebrachhold.de" sitemap-generator-version="4.0.8" -->
<!-- generated-on="June 11, 2017 6:05 pm" -->
<sitemapindex xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/siteindex.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> <sitemap>
        <loc>http://MY_SITE/sitemap-misc.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2017-05-31T20:49:06+00:00</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://MY_SITE/sitemap-pt-post-2017-04.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2017-04-12T16:27:52+00:00</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
    <sitemap>
        <loc>http://MY_SITE/sitemap-pt-post-2017-02.xml</loc>
        <lastmod>2017-02-10T17:50:14+00:00</lastmod>
    </sitemap>
[...]
</sitemapindex>
```

And each subsitemap then like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://MY_SITE/wp-content/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/sitemap.xsl"?><!-- sitemap-generator-url="http://www.arnebrachhold.de" sitemap-generator-version="4.0.8" -->
<!-- generated-on="June 11, 2017 6:07 pm" -->
<urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"> <url>
        <loc>http://MY_SITE/32017-SOME_CONTENT/</loc>
        <lastmod>2017-04-12T16:27:52+00:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>http://MY_SITE/32017-SOME_OTHER_CONTENT/</loc>
        <lastmod>2017-04-12T16:24:25+00:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that unlike the links in HTML, `wget -r` is unable to follow links in XML. You could work around this by retrieving the sitemap first, finding all the URLs in it and finally retrieve them with another `wget`, e.g.:

```
wget --quiet http://example.com/sitemap.xml --output-document - \
    | egrep -o "http://example\.com[^<]+" \
    | wget -i - --wait 0
```

Here, the key is

> `-i file`
>
> `--input-file=file`
>
> Read URLs from a local or external file.
>   If `-` is specified as file, URLs are read from the standard input.
>   (Use `./-` to read from a file literally named `-`.) If this function
>   is used, no URLs need be present on the command line. If there are
>   URLs both on the command line and in an input file, those on the
>   command lines will be the first ones to be retrieved. If
>   `--force-html` is not specified, then file should consist of a series
>   of URLs, one per line.

We offer this "file" from standard input after modifying the XML into desired form i.e. one URL per line with `egrep`.

Answer (score 0):

If the site displays the sitemap as HTML, but returns it to you as XML, there is probably an .xsl or .xslt (eXtensible Stylesheet Language Transformation) file you're missing. This defines how the XML file is actually displayed; in this case, probably in the form of HTML. If you download that and display it, it'll probably produce what you're looking for. Alternatively, you can learn XSLT and write your own.

Comment: No, there is no HTML display. That is a xml format so that google can index your page faster. I'll edit an example in my question.